# Error in Mongoimport due to the db

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, jupyter

I am a beginner in python and mongodb.

I want to import json file named club_members.json to the database which the database didn't exist yet. As far as I know, mongodb will create the db name automatically when the code is run. Here is my code

```
 def get_collection():
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')  
    db = client.club      
mongoimport --db club --colletion members_collection --type json --file club_members.json

return None
```

The db variable is made for making database named club which didn't exist yet. But then, it gave me errors like this

```
mongoimport --db club --colletion members_collection --type json --file club_members.json
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I am checking the database list by using `client.database_names()` function, it returns no club database. So, I think this error is caused by the existence of the db. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: No, this is caused by you attempting to put a shell command directly into Python code. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner. this is my first attempt. please, explaine me how to fix that?

Comment: Take out that `mongoimport` line, which as the error indicates is not valid Python syntax.

Comment: Do you mean I shout write mongoimport code outside the function get_collection()?

Comment: No. I mean *you shouldn't put that code in your Python script* because it is not Python.

Comment: I think we might need a bit more context information here. like Daniel said you have put shell commands into Python codes, like you have mixed English with Japanese, computer can't understand it. you need firstly, delete this line of codes; then you should check mongodb's api again to find out what the function you need to call to achieve your purpose. try that.

Comment: I see. Thank you guys. I understood my mistakes. I used jupyter. and I think I shout write it in the %%bash space.